# Efficiently Parsing Large JSON Files in Python: Best Practices and Performance Optimization

Tags: python, json

I need to efficiently read and process huge JSON files because I'm using Python to work with them. I need advice on best practises and speed optimisation methods for processing such large files because JSON files can be several gigabytes to terabytes in size.

Specifically, I'm curious to know:

1. Considering memory utilisation and processing performance, effective methods for reading and parsing big JSON files in Python. Are there any particular streaming methodologies, techniques, or libraries that can help with this?
2. Reducing memory cost, limiting object generation, and improving data extraction are methods for processing complicated JSON structures and nested data effectively.
3. methods for dividing or parallelizing JSON processing workloads to make better use of several CPU cores or machines
4. any possible bottlenecks, frequent mistakes to avoid when working with huge JSON files, and suggestions for avoiding them.

Any tips, code samples, suggested libraries, or reference materials that will help me successfully handle the difficulties of parsing and processing huge JSON files in Python are gratefully appreciated. I appreciate your insightful advice in advance.